# Getting active type within a date range that was logged in or out of that date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a client type history table. It's really a view pulling audit and client data together but let's call it tTypeHistory. It also wouldn't be grouped by client ID, but I was trying to make it easy to read.

Here is some example data:

```
iClientID | IClientType | dEffectiveDate
1         | 6           | 8/1/2016
1         | 7           | 8/30/2016
1         | 8           | 9/30/2016
2         | 6           | 8/15/2016
2         | 7           | 9/5/2016
2         | 8           | 10/2/2016
3         | 6           | 9/15/2016
3         | 8           | 10/12/2016
```

I can find out what a client type was on a  particular date fairly easily:

```
SELECT TOP 1 iClientType 
FROM tTypeHistory 
WHERE iClientID = 1 dEffectiveDate <= '9/1/2016'
```

I can find anyone who was ever client type 7 easily as well, but what I'm trying to do is figure out who was a type 7 within a range, usually a month, but could be any specific range.

I could search for effective date between 9/1-9/30 for type 7 and I find client ID 2, but that doesn't find client 1. They were type 7 from 8/30 until they changed to type 8 on 9/30, but it could have changed on 10/30, etc...

I feel like the answer shouldn't be that elusive, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not as straight forward as it seems.  The main reason is that each row only has the Effective Date and is missing the End Date.  The query below figures out the End Date and then selects the desired iClientID's:

```
with cte
AS
(
    select *, 
    (select top 1 dEffectiveDate 
       from @TypeHistory t 
      where t.iClientID = t1.iClientID and t.dEffectiveDate > t1.dEffectiveDate
      order by t.dEffectiveDate) as dEndDate
    from @TypeHistory t1
)
select distinct iClientID 
  from cte
 where iClientType = 7
   and (   dEffectiveDate between '9/1/2016' and '9/30/2016' 
        or dEndDate between '9/1/2016' and '9/30/2016'
        or (dEndDate is null and dEffectiveDate < '9/1/2016'));
```

EDIT: Changed the 'where' clause to address the scenario where iClientType changed multiple times within the date range.

Comment: I'm still doing some testing against the real data, but it looks like you did it! That was fast! My team has spent hours on this to no avail. Thanks!!

Comment: Please note a change on the `where` clause to address a particular scenario.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that was a possible case. For instance someone became a 7 on 9/15 and then something else on 9/16, but it looks like your adjustment catches that case. Thanks!

Comment: It needed one more qualifier for when the type is set before the range and changed after the range.  

or (dEffectiveDate < '9/1/2016' AND dEndDate > '9/30/2016')

I also limited the the t1 since we don't care about effective dates after the range, except where they serve as end dates: